# JQuery AJAX async false not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm writing a jQuery for send list of form datas one by one to server.

It working perfectly on Firefox, but when i use chrome it's sending all data at once

Here is my code

```
    $('.frmroldcon').each(function(){       
                var thobj=this;         
                $(thobj).prev().prev().prev('.failedicoconold').hide();
                $(thobj).prev('.doneicoconold').hide();
                $(thobj).prev().prev('.proccesicoconold').show();

                fuser = jQuery('input[name="fusername"]',thobj).val();
                fpass = jQuery('input[name="fpassword"]',thobj).val();


                  $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           async: false,
           cache:false,
           url: "checkcon.php",
           data: { checkcons: "1", fusername: fuser, fpassword: fpass},
           success: function(data){
                $(thobj).prev().prev('.proccesicoconold').hide();
                              if(data==0){
                                 $(thobj).prev().prev().prev('.failedicoconold').show();
                                  window.errc=window.errc+1;
                              }
                              else{
                                  $(thobj).prev('.doneicoconold').show();

 }                        

           }
              });                               
            });
```

I'm using jQuery version 2.1.4, also tried other old versions like 1.4 but it seems not working.

Can anyone give me a solution for this or alternative for submit each forms data to server one by one,

Thanks a lot

Comment: synchronous ajax requests are no longer allowed by chrome (nor should they be, they result in a terrible user experience. Fix it by doing things using callbacks instead of using synchronous requests. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/01/Getting-Rid-of-Synchronous-XHRs You have the option of waiting for each request to finish before making the next one, or doing them all simultaneously (using one request maybe?)

Comment: I'm using some php imap function calling with ajax, if i use async true it will send around 60 request at once and crash server, is there have any other alternative for for do that

Comment: Yes, change your architecture so instead of sending 60 requests at once you only send the request(s) you need to send. I don't see anything in your to indicate these requests need to be done in serial. Why can't you just make one and pass all the data along in the single request and let the server do the looping?

Comment: hmm i'll try some another logic without using jQuery each function

Comment: That's the wrong way to do it. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

A quick way to do serial, asynchronous, ajax requests using jQuery's `$.when`

```
var requests = [];

$('.frmroldcon').each(function() {
    $.when.apply($,requests).then(function() {
       requests.push($.ajax({/* your ajax request */});
    });
});
```

You haven't shown the requirement to have to do these requests serially, however. And if you can do everything you need to do with 1 call to the server instead of 60, then that's the way you should be doing it.